# How to run a script during boot as root after user desktop is loaded

Tags: x11, root, autostart

I have a script that starts dropbox as user **dropbox**. I want it to automatically start after desktop environment is loaded. Desktop environment is running as **another user** not "dropbox".

When I run it with:

`root@localhost:/home/gameboy# /etc/init.d/dropbox start`

it works ok.

But I need it to start automatically. I put a Desktop Entry file to `/etc/xdg/autostart/` but I did not succeed:

```
gameboy@localhost:~$ sudo cat /etc/xdg/autostart/dropbox.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
Exec=/etc/init.d/dropbox start
Icon=dropbox
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;

gameboy@localhost:~$ sudo cat /etc/init.d/dropbox
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: dropbox
# Required-Start: 
# Required-Stop: 
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the dropbox service
# Description: starts dropbox using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

xhost +SI:localuser:dropbox &>/dev/null
DAEMON2=/usr/local/dropbox/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-20.4.19/dropbox

DROPBOX_USERS="dropbox"
DAEMON=/usr/local/dropbox/dropboxd
#unset DISPLAY

start() {
   echo "Starting dropbox..."
   for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
      HOMEDIR=$(getent passwd $dbuser | cut -d: -f6)
      if [ -x $DAEMON ]; then
         HOME="$HOMEDIR" start-stop-daemon -b -o -c $dbuser -S -u $dbuser -x $DAEMON
      fi
   done
}

stop() {
   echo "Stopping dropbox..."
   for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
      HOMEDIR=$(getent passwd $dbuser | cut -d: -f6)
      if [ -x $DAEMON2 ]; then
         start-stop-daemon -o -c $dbuser -K -u $dbuser -x $DAEMON2
      fi
   done
}

status() {
   for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
   dbpid=$(pgrep -u $dbuser dropbox)
   if [ -z "$dbpid" ] ; then
      echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: not running."
   else
      echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: running (pid $dbpid)"
   fi
   done
}

case "$1" in
   start)
      start
      sleep 1
      status
      ;;

   stop)
      stop
      sleep 1
      status
      ;;

   restart|reload|force-reload)
      stop
      start
      sleep 1
      status
      ;;

   status)
      status
      ;;

   *)
      echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/dropbox {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}"
      exit 1

esac

exit 0
gameboy@localhost:~$
```

How to make it start automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Been a while of course, but again for others.. this is a daemon service which needs root privileges; thus, running it in a desktop file in autostart won't do what you wanted.

WHat you wanted to do instead was to use your init system's daemon control (e.g. /etc/init.d/dropbox) and add that to your *init* daemopn's control, and as you can see, it should run in your graphical runlevels.

If you happen not to have admin rights, there is no way for you to start it as a privileged daemon as a normal user. Else if you do, look up the manual for the init which uses the init.d scripts you linked.

(I know this is late but is for other users).

Comment: Thing is, not many distros are still using old style sysv init scripts. Depending on distro you may need systemd .service files, etc.

Comment: And it would be nice if you would say at least *a little bit* more about what the user needs to do — “look up the manual for the init…” is very vague.